# Listing next date/time triggered scheduled tasks

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to list the scheduled tasks on Windows 10 that have a date+time based trigger?

I want to find out if my computer will be woken up by a scheduled task if I put it in standby mode.

Some times the computer is woken up after just a few minutes because of a scheduled task (and of course it then stays awake).

Comment: Does the following PowerShell command help: `Get-ScheduledTask  | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo  | Sort-Object Nextruntime | select Taskname, LastRunTime, NextRunTime | Out-GridView`

Comment: Or just those tasks that are set to wake the computer to run: `Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun}` or `Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun -and $_.State -ne 'Disabled'} |  Get-ScheduledTaskInfo  | Sort-Object Nextruntime | select Taskname, LastRunTime, NextRunTime | Out-GridView`

Answer (score 0):

The Task Scheduler can do this list:

- Start the Task Scheduler
- Click on "Task Scheduler Library"
- Click "Next Run Time" to sort the list by order of run time.

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to also see the tasks from sub-folders of the "Task Scheduler Library"? It is also difficult to see if a task can reactivate the computer or not. There seems to be no additional column for showing this property.

Comment: By the way, the computer normally should go back to sleep after the task is done.

Comment: Even if the task triggered was installing Windows updates which caused a reboot?

Comment: Especially in that case.